# g++ in red hat devtoolset-3 cannot find -lelf

Tags: gcc, centos, elf, devtoolset

Hi I'm running devtoolset-3 on centos 6.5.

When I run g++, ld fails because it can't find -lelf

I compiled with the -v flag to find the library path g++ is using to find libraries, and have moved libelf.so into each of these folders however it is still not working.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas? Is -lelf not libelf.so? Should this file be in some place else besides the library paths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

---

Finding the package that provides libelf.so : # `yum provides libelf.so`

---

```
# yum install elfutils-libelf-devel
```

---